# dynamically create five rectangle in different position of the canvas using easeljs

Tags: canvas, easeljs

here i am trying to create five dynamic rectangle which will be positioned randomly on the canvas.i made a for loop to create the canvas.but only one rectangle is apperaing on the canvas let alone five.why the rest of the four rectangles are not appearing on the canvas.what's the problem here and how it can be fixed?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/humptydumpty45/TseQ2/1/)

```
<html>
<head>
   <style>
     *{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
   </style>
<script src="easeljs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <canvas id="mycanvas" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
<script>
   function init(){

     var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
     canvas.width = 500;
     canvas.height = 550;

     var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
     for (i=0;i<5;i++){
     var shape=new createjs.Shape();

     shape.graphics.beginFill('red').drawRect(stage.canvas.width-Math.floor(Math.random()+200),Math.floor(Math.random())+20,30,30);
     stage.addChild(shape);
     stage.update();


}

}
window.onload=init;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math.Random()` does generate a number between 0 and 1. So most of your numbers will be 200 for x and 20 for y because of the `floor` call. Sometimes it will be 201 for x and 21 for y, but maybe that's hard to see on the screen. I think what you probably want to do is the following:

```
function init(){

    var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
    canvas.width = 500;
    canvas.height = 550;

    var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        var shape=new createjs.Shape();
        shape.graphics.beginFill('red').drawRect(stage.canvas.width-Math.floor(Math.random()*200),Math.floor(Math.random()*20),30,30);
        stage.addChild(shape);
        stage.update();
    }
}
```

This will generate numbers between 0 and 200 for x and between 0 and 20 for y.